# Is it possible to export fur on a kitten, created use the new hair tool from 3.3, into gltf?

Tags: particles, bezier-curves, hair, gltf

New Blender user here, trying to learn the ropes :>

I've added some fur on a (rigged and animated) kitten mesh using the new blender hair tool which uses curves. It looks good and nice performance too.

I want to export it to gltf to use in Three.js, but the fur is not visible because gltf doesn't support curves or particles, only meshes.

I've tried a few things, like adding a Curve to Mesh geonode to the hair curves, going to curves -> convert to -> mesh and converting hair curves to particles and then turning them into mesh (in this case, new mesh for hair doesn't follow armature/animations, even if I join). The fur will not show after the export.

Should I conclude that it's impossible to have hair/fur on a gltf created by the new hair tool or is there a way for them to show?

Comment: The short answer is: [hair cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Glci.jpg). You can use your groomed hair curves for the layout so it's not a waste. I'll post an answer later. Sorry for the teaser, but right now don't have the time to write it down completely.

Comment: Blender can export meshes, loose edges, and loose points to glTF. Some other formats may only support meshes. Anything else would likely need to be baked down to those, but if it's fully baked (all modifiers applied etc.) then there should be no reason it won't export.